# How to load uiCollection View Cell form API

Tags: ios, swift, api, web-services, uicollectionview

I have created the uiCollection View programmatically.
I want to populate that uiCollection View with data coming from url in Model class from web service

```
struct AppCategory1 {
    let id, name, description, url, price : String
}

static func fetchFeatureApp(completionHandler:@escaping ([AppCategory1])->()){
    let urlString="http://ebmacs.net/ubereats/Api/all_product?id=1"
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: url)){ (data, responce, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        do {
            if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data!) as? [String:Any] {
                if let products = jsonResult["products"] as? [[String:String]] {
                    var appCategories = [AppCategory1]()
                    for product in products {
                        let category = AppCategory1(id: product["product_id"] ?? "",
                                                    name: product["product_name"] ?? "",
                                                    description: product["product_description"] ?? "",
                                                    url: product["image_url"] ?? "",
                                                    price: product["product_price"] ?? "")
                        appCategories.append(category)
                    }
                    print("Abc=")
                    print(appCategories)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { completionHandler(appCategories) }


                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        }.resume()

}
```

Until now uicollection view is being populated from data hard coded in function sampleAppCategories() in Model.swift file function is called from ViewController.swift file

```
 appcategories=AppCategory.sampleAppCategories()
```

I am calling this function fetchFeatureApp(completionHandler:@escaping ([AppCategory1])->()) from viewDidLoad function of FeaturedViewController class in ViewController.swift file

```
 AppCategory.fetchFeatureApp { (appcategories) in
            //self.appcategories = appcategories
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
```

It is not populating the uiCollection View.How i can populate the Collection View from url?

The issue is i hard coded uiCollectionviewController using AppCategory class

```
class AppCategory: NSObject {
        var name:NSString?
        var apps:[App]?
    }
    class App:NSObject  {
        var product_id:NSNumber?
        var product_name:String?
        var product_description:String?
        var image_url:String?
        var product_price:NSNumber?
        var name:String?
    }
```

and using AppCategory1 struct for getting data from url

```
struct AppCategory1 {
            let id, name, description, url, price : String
        }  //using for getting data url
```

I am trying to adopt one either struct or class for making the appearance of url data possible in collection view

You can download the project from this link .https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eBcbOLwtEdrCpZ3tDF41_WFsqPlgGo2r/view?usp=sharing

Comment: make sure that `self.appcategories` contains some data, check that you have set the collection view data source `self.collectionView.datasource = self` and that the UICollectionViewDataSource protocol has been implemented properly.

Comment: In collectionview controller datasource should be the same as  type 'appCategories' . collectionview delegate you taking different which is binded there. it should be same  type and you should assign to them in function ->  AppCategory.fetchFeatureApp { (appcategories) in
            self.appcategories = appcategories // this one have the same type of "self.appcategories"
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }

Comment: I have edited my question ..The issue is i hard coded uiCollectionviewController using AppCategory class and using AppCategory1 struct for getting data from url .I am trying to adopt one either struct or class for making the appearance of url data possible in collection view